# Why does TypeORM Execute SELECT queries with multiple OR statements for relation IDs?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with NestJS and MySQL.

I've noticed that this particular query appears frequently in RDS performance insights, and it's causing performance issues. The query selects id and user_id (relation id of user table) from user_auth table. This query has high Load by waits and Avg latency (ms)/call.

```
SELECT `user_auth`.`id` AS `id`, `user_auth`.`user_id` AS `user_id` 
FROM `user_auth` `user_auth` 
WHERE ((`user_auth`.`user_id` = ?) 
OR (`user_auth`.`user_id` = ?)
OR (`user_auth`.`user_id` = ?) 
OR...
```

I'm curious about why this query occurs so frequently. How can I go about resolving this performance issue?
I couldn't find method finding many `user_auth.id` on my code.

Something suspicious is that User and UserAuth Entity have a OneToOne relationship.

user-auth.entity.ts

```
  @Field(() => User)
  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.auth, {
    createForeignKeyConstraints: false,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: User;

  @Field(() => ID)
  @RelationId((userAuth: UserAuth) => userAuth.user)
  userId: number;
```

user.entity.ts

```
  @Field(() => UserAuth, {
    nullable: true,
  })
  @OneToOne(() => UserAuth, (userAuth) => userAuth.user)
  auth: UserAuth;

  @Field(() => ID)
  @RelationId((user: User) => user.auth)
  authId: number;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.

The `@RelationId` `authId` was the cause - when I deleted it, that SQL was no longer executed.

It looks like the query was trying to read from the `user_auth` table because the `user` table doesn't have a `auth_id`.